# sequelize: how to compare dates

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am having a table oauth_refresh_token like you can see below:

```
var OAuthRefreshToken = myDb.define("oauth_refresh_token", {
    refresh_token: {type: sequelize.STRING, primaryKey: true} 
    client_id:    {type: sequelize.STRING}                      
});
```

Sequelize automatically creates the columns "created_at" and "updated_at" for me with the datatype: "timestamp with time zone".

Now when I want to ask how to compare 2 dates with each other. I want to get an Object of this type if it was created in the last 24h.
I have something like this so far:

```
var currentTimeMinus24Hours = new Date()-24*60*60*1000;
return OAuthRefreshToken.find(
    where: {
        refresh_token: token
        updated_at: { gt: currentTimeMinus24Hours }
    }
)
```

If I do this code I get an exception that operator does not exists: timestamp with time zone > bigint. Makes sense, but any Idea how I can make it work. If it helps you. I am using a postgres database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the momentjs library

http://momentjs.com/

calling `moment().format()` will give you the date time in timestamptz format.

There are also many reasons why you should use moment because it is a solid library that deals away with many problems associated with manipulating time.

However I am interested to see if there are other vanilla solutions.

Comment: I forgot you mention that you can either do:

`moment(new Date()-24*60*60*1000).format()`, or in the moment style: `moment().format().substract(24,'hours')`

Comment: It's `moment().subtract().format()` - notice the order _and_ `subtract` vs `substract`.

Comment: Moment mutates the time so you can end up with some interesting side effects if you're not careful. For a newer solution, look into date-fns.